# Employees permissions to add and edit only their products

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I want to set employees permisions to add and edit only their products (Prestashop 1.6.x). I know Prestashop doesn't save employees info in `product`s table, however, is it possible to make such functionality in a quick way? If I had employee ID in product table I'll be able to limit the permissions just for editing their products. But how can I add employee ID to the `product` table? Which file should I modify? And how can I add new row to `ps_product` table?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible theoretically, but very long, because it would override the product class, Image, categories, etc ... modify the Prestashop tables, so all this would make your shop unstable, and difficult to evolve thereafter.

What I would recommend is either spent in multiboutique, with a store per employee. So each employee could modify only his products or use a module like this one https://addons.prestashop.com/en/marketplace-creation/18656-ja-marketplace.html

Regards,